# Recryler in imageview how to make invisible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, imageview, visibility

How do I fix this issue?
ı want to recylerview in Imageview make INVISIBLE but it doesn't work
my codes are below
and sory for my bad english :)
this movement in many places but I could not find the source

```
class CevaplarRecylerAdapter(
                         private val username: ArrayList<String>,
                         private val comment: ArrayList<String>,
                         )
:RecyclerView.Adapter<CevaplarRecylerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): CevaplarRecylerAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_layout, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CevaplarRecylerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.UsernameText?.text=username[position]
    holder.LoadAnswerText?.text=comment[position]
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return username.size
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    var UsernameText:TextView?=null
    var LoadAnswerText:TextView?=null
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    var kontrol:ImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.drawable.cevap)

    init {
        LoadAnswerText=itemView.findViewById(R.id.LoadAnswerTexttv)
        UsernameText=itemView.findViewById(R.id.UsernameTexttv)
        kontrol.visibility = View.INVISIBLE; // ı want to this view make Invisiable          
    }
}
interface OnItemClickListener {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it

```
class CevaplarRecylerAdapter(
                         private val username: ArrayList<String>,
                         private val comment: ArrayList<String>,
                         private val check:Boolean
                         )
:RecyclerView.Adapter<CevaplarRecylerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): CevaplarRecylerAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_layout, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CevaplarRecylerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.UsernameText?.text=username[position]
    holder.LoadAnswerText?.text=comment[position]
    var a=true
    if (a==true){
        Picasso.get().load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/egitimnoktasilast.appspot.com/o/images%2F06b57525-0f40-4f86-9fae-8dc6082aab7e.jpg?alt=media&token=5183e857-2252-48b3-bbca-f96a0517ddce").into(holder.photo)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return username.size
}



inner class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    var UsernameText:TextView?=null
    var LoadAnswerText:TextView?=null
       var photo:ImageView?=null


    init {
        LoadAnswerText=itemView.findViewById(R.id.LoadAnswerTexttv)
        UsernameText=itemView.findViewById(R.id.UsernameTexttv)
        photo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.Rightimage)
        Visibility(check)
    }

     fun Visibility(check: Boolean){
        if (check==true){
            photo!!.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        }
         else{
            photo!!.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
        }
    }



}

interface OnItemClickListener {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in your `ViewHolder` findViewById your imageView by its id not a drawable

change this line

```
 @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
 var kontrol:ImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.drawable.cevap)
```

to

```
var kontrol:ImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add id of your imageview at place of drawable as below -

Replace this

```
   var kontrol:ImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.drawable.cevap)
```

with this

```
   var kontrol:ImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourimageviewid)
```